# DateTime to quarter end in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeoffset

My current date is in this format "202003", "202006", "202009". I want to change it to "2020-03-31", "2020-06-30", "2020-09-30".

Here is my code:

```
df6['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df6['Date'], format = "%Y%m").dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df6['Date'] = df6['Date'] + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.offsets.QuarterEnd' and 'str'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the date offset ***before*** converting to string with `strftime`, Ex:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["202003", "202006", "202009"]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%Y%m") + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(0)

df['Date_str'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df.head()
        Date    Date_str
0 2020-03-31  2020-03-31
1 2020-06-30  2020-06-30
2 2020-09-30  2020-09-30

df.dtypes
Date        datetime64[ns]
Date_str            object
dtype: object
```